# ES6 Reduce nested objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, reduce

I've been using map and reduce over some objects and arrays which have been working well so far, however I'm having trouble with one array.

Example of data here:

```
var arr =
[
[
{
  "id": 6501511,
  "invoiceId": {
    "id": 1043773
  },
  "chargeBandType": "TIME",
  "jobTaskId": {
    "id": 19399852
  },
  "invoicedNet": {
    "amountString": 0,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "invoicedTaxOneOtherCurrency": null,
  "invoicedTaxOne": {
    "amountString": 0,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "taxOneRate": 0.1
},
{
  "id": 6501517,
  "invoiceId": {
    "id": 1043773
  },
  "chargeBandType": "TIME",
  "jobTaskId": null,
  "jobExpenseId": null,
  "jobThirdPartyCostId": {
    "id": 20602
  },
  "invoicedNet": {
    "amountString": 0,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "invoicedTaxOneOtherCurrency": null,
  "invoicedTaxOne": {
    "amountString": 0,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "taxOneRate": 0.1
},
{
  "id": 6501508,
  "invoiceId": {
    "id": 13773
  },
  "chargeBandType": "TIME",
  "jobTaskId": {
    "id": 19398574
  },
  "invoicedNet": {
    "amountString": 30,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "invoicedTaxOneOtherCurrency": null,
  "invoicedTaxOne": {
    "amountString": 3,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "taxOneRate": 0.1
},
{
  "id": 65014,
  "invoiceId": {
    "id": 104
  },
  "chargeBandType": "TIME",
  "jobTaskId": null,
  "jobExpenseId": null,
  "jobThirdPartyCostId": {
    "id": 206
  },
  "invoicedNet": {
    "amountString": 0,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "invoicedTaxOneOtherCurrency": null,
  "invoicedTaxOne": {
    "amountString": 0,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "taxOneRate": 0.1
}],
[
{
  "id": 6483,
  "invoiceId": {
    "id": 1042400
  },
  "chargeBandType": "TIME",
  "jobTaskId": {
    "id": 198574
  },
  "invoicedNet": {
    "amountString": 100,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "invoicedTaxOneOtherCurrency": null,
  "invoicedTaxOne": {
    "amountString": 10,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "taxOneRate": 0.1
}
]
];
```

I am trying to reduce the values of invoicedNet.amountString, which would bring a sum of 130 in the case above.

I have tried many ways to work this, including functions similar to the below:

```
var sum = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
return a += b.invoicedNet.amountString;
}, 0);
```

However, no matter how I try this,  I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'amountString' of undefined
```

*(It seems to pick up b.invoicedNet as an object though).*

Could anyone suggest an approach to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to loop both arrays.

```js
var arr = [[{ id: 6501511, invoiceId: { id: 1043773 }, chargeBandType: "TIME", jobTaskId: { id: 19399852 }, invoicedNet: { amountString: 0, currencyType: "USD" }, invoicedTaxOneOtherCurrency: null, invoicedTaxOne: { amountString: 0, currencyType: "USD" }, taxOneRate: 0.1 }, { id: 6501517, invoiceId: { id: 1043773 }, chargeBandType: "TIME", jobTaskId: null, jobExpenseId: null, jobThirdPartyCostId: { id: 20602 }, invoicedNet: { amountString: 0, currencyType: "USD" }, invoicedTaxOneOtherCurrency: null, invoicedTaxOne: { amountString: 0, currencyType: "USD" }, taxOneRate: 0.1 }, { id: 6501508, invoiceId: { id: 13773 }, chargeBandType: "TIME", jobTaskId: { id: 19398574 }, invoicedNet: { amountString: 30, currencyType: "USD" }, invoicedTaxOneOtherCurrency: null, invoicedTaxOne: { amountString: 3, currencyType: "USD" }, taxOneRate: 0.1 }, { id: 65014, invoiceId: { id: 104 }, chargeBandType: "TIME", jobTaskId: null, jobExpenseId: null, jobThirdPartyCostId: { id: 206 }, invoicedNet: { amountString: 0, currencyType: "USD" }, invoicedTaxOneOtherCurrency: null, invoicedTaxOne: { amountString: 0, currencyType: "USD" }, taxOneRate: 0.1 }], [{ id: 6483, invoiceId: { id: 1042400 }, chargeBandType: "TIME", jobTaskId: { id: 198574 }, invoicedNet: { amountString: 100, currencyType: "USD" }, invoicedTaxOneOtherCurrency: null, invoicedTaxOne: { amountString: 10, currencyType: "USD" }, taxOneRate: 0.1 }]],
    sum = arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
        b.forEach(function (c) {
            a += c.invoicedNet.amountString;
        });
        return a;
    }, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this quite neatly by flattening the arrays first and then reducing:

```
[].concat(...arr)
  .map(invoice => invoice.invoicedNet.amountString)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b)
```

Comment: I'm not one for premature optimization, but your `map`ping is really not necessary - why do two loops when one will suffice?

Comment: Just find it to be neater. It's clearer that you are extracting that value and then summing.

Answer (score 1):

Flatten your array, then reduce:

```
[].concat(...arr).reduce((a, { invoicedNet: { amountString }}) => a + amountString, 0)
```

```js
var arr =
[
[
{
  "id": 6501511,
  "invoiceId": {
    "id": 1043773
  },
  "chargeBandType": "TIME",
  "jobTaskId": {
    "id": 19399852
  },
  "invoicedNet": {
    "amountString": 0,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "invoicedTaxOneOtherCurrency": null,
  "invoicedTaxOne": {
    "amountString": 0,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "taxOneRate": 0.1
},
{
  "id": 6501517,
  "invoiceId": {
    "id": 1043773
  },
  "chargeBandType": "TIME",
  "jobTaskId": null,
  "jobExpenseId": null,
  "jobThirdPartyCostId": {
    "id": 20602
  },
  "invoicedNet": {
    "amountString": 0,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "invoicedTaxOneOtherCurrency": null,
  "invoicedTaxOne": {
    "amountString": 0,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "taxOneRate": 0.1
},
{
  "id": 6501508,
  "invoiceId": {
    "id": 13773
  },
  "chargeBandType": "TIME",
  "jobTaskId": {
    "id": 19398574
  },
  "invoicedNet": {
    "amountString": 30,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "invoicedTaxOneOtherCurrency": null,
  "invoicedTaxOne": {
    "amountString": 3,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "taxOneRate": 0.1
},
{
  "id": 65014,
  "invoiceId": {
    "id": 104
  },
  "chargeBandType": "TIME",
  "jobTaskId": null,
  "jobExpenseId": null,
  "jobThirdPartyCostId": {
    "id": 206
  },
  "invoicedNet": {
    "amountString": 0,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "invoicedTaxOneOtherCurrency": null,
  "invoicedTaxOne": {
    "amountString": 0,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "taxOneRate": 0.1
}],
[
{
  "id": 6483,
  "invoiceId": {
    "id": 1042400
  },
  "chargeBandType": "TIME",
  "jobTaskId": {
    "id": 198574
  },
  "invoicedNet": {
    "amountString": 100,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "invoicedTaxOneOtherCurrency": null,
  "invoicedTaxOne": {
    "amountString": 10,
    "currencyType": "USD"
  },
  "taxOneRate": 0.1
}
]
];

console.log([].concat(...arr).reduce((a, { invoicedNet: { amountString }}) => a + amountString, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
return a += b.invoicedNet.amountString;
}, 0);
```

The above code doesn't work because *arr* is a multidimensional array. Its elements are also an array. You need a nested reducer for this type of array. with the arrow function, it can be written as -

```
const total = arr.reduce((sum, tasks) => tasks.reduce((previousSum, task) =>
              previousSum + task.invoicedNet.amountString, sum) , 0);
```